# Continuity of Borel measurable Gleason frame functions

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Gleason's theorem (Journal of Mathematics and Mechanics, Vol. 6, No. 6, 1957) classifies measures on the closed subspaces of a separable Hilbert space. A key lemma toward the proof of the theorem asserts the following. Let f be a nonnegative real-valued function on the 2-sphere in 3-space with the property that its sum on any triple of orthogonal points is independent of the triple. Then f is continuous. The question is whether the conclusion remains valid if one drops the nonnegativity assumption and
assumes Borel measurability instead.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this could help
http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.4504
bye
W.

Comment: Gleason theorem (for von Neumann algebras, and even JBW algebras,
without type I_2 part) has been extended to signed / complex 
measures (and even suitable vector valued measures). S.Maeda, 
Bunce and Maitland wright wrote surveys around 20 years ago.